# How to build a side button that open above leaving content in background

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I want to make a button just like http://www.snappages.com/ in which the help button is on right side on which one click the new box is open leaving the content behind. How to do this from scratch.

Comment: You have anything to give us an idea of what you want? that link has several buttons on it. Maybe some code you've already written.

Comment: You want a [modal dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)?

Comment: http://wpaoli.building58.com/2009/09/jquery-tab-slide-out-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To position the button at right:

Use css fixed positioning with right as 0

To create an overlay

make elements like:

```
<div id="overlay">
<div id="help">
</div>
</div>
```

with css:

```
#overlay{
position:fixed;
display:none;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:rgb(255,255,255);
background:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

Inside the overlay make your actual help form
position it absolute and center it

```
#help{
position:absolute;
left:50%;
width:300px;
margin-left:-150px;
top:100px;
}
```

And on clicking the help button

```
$('#help-button').on('click',function(){
  $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast');
  });
```